# JQuery Ajax to send Sortable Array in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm picking up items from a `ul`, and turning into an array. My controller is below and the variable `items` is getting empty​​.

What should I do to the controller receiving the correct value.

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GravarConfiguracao(string[] itens)
{
    var indicaores = itens;
    var sequencia = 1;
    foreach (var item in indicaores)
    {
        var atualizaIndicador = IndicadoresDoUsuario.AtualizarSequencia(Usuario.Codigo, Convert.ToInt32(item), sequencia);
        sequencia++;                
    }

    return Json(new { HttpStatusCode.OK });
}
```

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: makeUrl("Indicador/GravarConfiguracao"),    
    data: JSON.stringify({ itens: $("#sort1").sortable('toArray') }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (dados) {  

    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("Erro: - " + err);
    }
});
```

JQuery send:

```
Query String Parameters:
{"itens":["itemIndicador_3","itemIndicador_10","itemIndicador_11"]}:
```

Comment: try this:``data: { itens: $("#sort1").sortable('toArray') }`` and in code: ``(object itens)``

Comment: in code: `(object itens)` I did not @EhsanSajjad